# MessageMapping in WebSockets Spring is not being called even though stomp sent is working

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, annotations, spring-annotations

1. Message Mapping Controller

```
@Controller
public class MessageControl {


    @MessageMapping("/message")
    @SendTo("/topic/return")
    public Message getContent(Message message) {
        
        //to call this method we call /app/message
//        try {
//            //processing
////            Thread.sleep(2000);
//
//        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
        
        System.out.println("Returning message to subscribing items");
        return message;
    }

}
```

2. Send function in JavaScript from client side

```
function sendMessage(){


    let jsonOb={
        name:localStorage.getItem("name"),
        content:$("#message-value").val()
    }

   stompClient.send("/app/message",{},JSON.stringify(jsonOb));
    

}
```

3. Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class Config implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/server1").withSockJS();
      //this is the link where the client connects to the backend server
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic","/queue");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        //any request that is being sent to the broker needs to be through /app/topic
    }
}
```

4. Message class

```
public class Message {
    
        private String name;
        private String content;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
        public Message(String name, String content) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.content = content;
        }
        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }
    }
```

The browser console shows that the message is being sent to the server, but the server side Method defined for the message mapping does not get called, the system.out.println("") print statement does not get printed. So it means the mapping is not working for some reason.